# Concurrent version of LRU cache

Tags: java, caching, collections, concurrency

I've implemented LRU CAche in java. It works perfectly. I used two data structures: hashMap for fast retrieving existing elements and DoubleLinkedList for keeping order of nodes. However I'm confused how I can provide efficient concurrency mechanism for my implementation? I started with locking conception, but would like to ensure fast reading without synchronization with writing and I stuck here because it looks like I cannot do this.

Could you please advise me how I can provdie concurrency for my LRU implementation avoiding inelegant locking on whole cache? Below is my code:

```
public class LRUCacheImpl implements LRUCache {
    private final Map<Integer, Node> cacheMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private final DoubleLinkedList nodeList;
    private final int allowedCapacity;

    public LRUCacheImpl(int allowedCapacity) {
        this.allowedCapacity = allowedCapacity;
        nodeList = new DoubleLinkedListImpl(allowedCapacity);
    }

    @Override
    public Node getElement(int value) {
        Node toReturn = cacheMap.get(value);
        if(toReturn != null){
            nodeList.moveExistingToHead(toReturn);
            toReturn = new Node(toReturn.getValue());
        }
        else{
            synchronized (this) {
                if (allowedCapacity == nodeList.getCurrentSize()) {
                    cacheMap.remove(nodeList.getTail().getValue());
                }
                toReturn = new Node(value);
                nodeList.addNewAsHead(toReturn);
                cacheMap.put(value, toReturn);
            }
        }
        return new Node(toReturn.getValue());
    }

    List<Node> getCacheState() {
        return nodeList.getAllElements();
    }
}

public class DoubleLinkedListImpl implements DoubleLinkedList {
    private Node head;
    private Node tail;
    private int currentSize;
    private final int allowedCapacity;

    public DoubleLinkedListImpl(int allowedCapacity) {
        this.currentSize = 0;
        this.allowedCapacity = allowedCapacity;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized int getCurrentSize() {
        return currentSize;
    }

   @Override
   public synchronized Node getTail() {
       return tail;
    }

    @Override
    public void moveExistingToHead(Node element) {
        if(element != null && element != head) {
            synchronized (this) {
                if(element != null && element != head) {
                    Node prev = element.getPrev();
                    Node next = element.getNext();
                    prev.setNext(next);
                    if (next != null) {
                        next.setPrev(prev);
                    } else {
                        tail = prev;
                    }
                    attachAsHead(element);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void addNewAsHead(Node element) {
        if(currentSize == 0){
            head = tail = element;
            currentSize = 1;
        }
        else if(currentSize < allowedCapacity){
            currentSize++;
            attachAsHead(element);
        }
        else{
            evictTail();
            attachAsHead(element);
        }
    }

    private synchronized void attachAsHead(Node element) {
        element.setPrev(null);
        element.setNext(head);
        head.setPrev(element);
        head = element;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized List<Node> getAllElements() {
        List<Node> nodes = new LinkedList<>();
        Node tmp = head;
        while(tmp != null){
            nodes.add(new Node(tmp.getValue()));
            tmp = tmp.getNext();
        }
        return nodes;
    }

    private synchronized void evictTail(){
        tail = tail.getPrev();
        tail.setNext(null);
        currentSize--;
    }
}

public class Node {
    private int value;
    private Node prev;
    private Node next;
    // getters and setters ommited
}
```

Comment: It's not simple. You'll need to CAS in a special "update in progress" object, read through to get the value, then CAS the special object with the value.

Comment: Could you please give me some details? What is CAS?

Comment: `AtomicReference.compareAndSet` is one example. There is an equivalent on `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: Could you please put here some sketch of your conception or code snippet? I've never used AtomicRefrence before and don;t understand how it can help in my case. Thank you.

Comment: Please read these [slides](https://github.com/ben-manes/concurrentlinkedhashmap/blob/wiki/ConcurrentCachingAtGoogle.pdf) and how it [evolved](http://highscalability.com/blog/2016/1/25/design-of-a-modern-cache.html). The solution is simple but not immediately obvious.

Comment: I'd be pretty dubious of a solution that tried to wrap a `ConcurrentHashMap` already.  Implementing this yourself is unlikely to go well.

Comment: @LouisWasserman By that do you mean that you prefer forking over decorating? I actually thought the gains of forking were lost by the high complexity cost.

Comment: @BenManes I was arguing for using an existing cache wholesale and not trying to fork, decorate, or otherwise mess with it.  Just use something that's already there.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Oh of course. I assumed this was a learning exercise.

Comment: @BenManes. Thank you for the links very much. They were very helpful. Yes. I implemented this as an exercise only - at least Java has built-in LRU cache in LinkedHashMap or I can use something more specialized like Caffeine or Ehcache. I'll attach my understanding of possible solution in the answer to this post. Please verify.

Comment: The correct solution is obviously to use a [Guava cache](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained).

Answer (score 0):

According to links from @BenManes I see that in classical approach of implementation cache, when we use HashMap and DoubleLinkedList, is impossible to match with concurrency. Only synchronized version is possible in such case. Currently I made the new version of my algorithm, using WeakReference in ConcurrentHashMap for storing nodes (@Marko Topolnik - are you sure you would like to use AtomicReference? Still can't get your way). IMHO this enables me to avoid synchronizing of reading with writing while getting existing element, because removing tail from list (eviction) will automatically remove node from hash map. Off course synchronization on list methods is still required. The only one weak point of this solution is we don't have control on GC, so it's possible potentially to obtain stale data from hashMap...

As I understood, to make LRU cache concurrent we need to change the implementation as follows (few possibilities):

- -locking only some parts of list
- -using probabilistic methods to find good victim for eviction
- -providing asynchronous pre-commit ring buffers (separate for reading and writing) and using state machine for entry life cycle to avoid
  reordering of operations